# Multi-key encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption

I am looking for a way to do multi-key encryption with the set number of decryption keys. The goal is to take a file, encrypt it and generate several decryption keys, in order to decrypt several (**not just one, but all either**) keys must be used.

Use case:

Receive image.jpeg
Generate an encrypted image.jpeg.crypt, image.jpeg.key1, image.jpeg.key2, image.jpeg.key3
Distribute keys to three different persons

After this 2 keys must be present to decrypt, but any 2 of the mentioned 3.

In perfect scenario i should be able to say: "Generate X keys, out of which Y keys will be required to decrypt".

P.S. This is not a duplicate of [Encryption strategies for multi users access in production systems](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4575/encryption-strategies-for-multi-users-access-in-production-systems) where any one key decrypts, nor is it a duplicate of [Doubling up or cycling encryption algorithms](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/doubling-up-or-cycling-encryption-algorithms) where every key must be provided.

Comment: I thin k the term you're looking for is 'quorum' encryption/decryption

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for [secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing) algorithms. Once such scheme was proposed by Shamir, called [Shamir's secret sharing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing).

Quoting from Wikipedia:

> ... a secret is divided into parts, giving each participant its own
>   unique part, where some of the parts or all of them are needed in
>   order to reconstruct the secret.